# How to overwrite Elastic Beanstalk environment variables through ebextensions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

My EB environment has some environment variables that I have set through the AWS web console. However, I'm now looking to have these env variables be set through ebextensions.

The problem is that it doesn't look like I am able to overwrite the variables that I initially set through the AWS web console.

Overwriting env vars that were explicitly set by ebextensions is fine, though.

Here's how my ebextensions file looks:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    oldVar: updatedTestValue
    newVar: newValue
```

`newVar` updates whenever I update my ebextensions file. However `oldVar`, which is a var I set through the console, refuses update.

Any thoughts on how I can have ebextensions work as desired? I'd really like to avoid a scenario where I have to remove my previously-set env vars and quickly deploy an update with the ebextensions changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs on precedence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-precedence), it seems that if you have set an environment variable using the console (or the API/SDK in general) then that value will take precedence over a value from `.ebextensions`. Unfortunately this implies that you will have to remove your previously set variables from the console and include them in your ebextensions instead.